# PyQt5 DatePicker Popup

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

[image]

I am not able to make datepicker in pyqt5. I am using calendarWidget and it working fine now. But i want dropdown datepicker in my menu bar and want to show selected date in lineEdit.

I have created a layout in QDesigner and adding 'DateEdit" widget. But i want same exactly as image shown.

I searched for datepicker and getting this link :[How to add Today Button in QDateEdit Pop-up QCalendarWidget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58959425/how-to-add-today-button-in-qdateedit-pop-up-qcalendarwidget)

I tried many approaches but it's not working.

Note: when i run my file dateEdit widget always show the Date:[01-01-2000]. it not showing the current date.

**datepicker.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.frame_2 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.frame_2.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_2.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_2.setObjectName("frame_2")
        self.verticalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.frame_2)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName("verticalLayout_2")
        self.frame = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.frame_2)
        self.frame.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(56, 122, 179);")
        self.frame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame.setObjectName("frame")
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.frame)
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frame)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(243, 243, 243);")
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.dateEdit = QtWidgets.QDateEdit(self.frame)
        self.dateEdit.setObjectName("dateEdit")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.dateEdit)
        spacerItem = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(40, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.horizontalLayout.addItem(spacerItem)
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.frame)
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.frame_2)
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(0)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(0)
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.tableWidget)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.frame_2)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Selected Date is :________________________"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: As an aside, you seem to be mixing multiple naming conventions, be careful!

Comment: @AMC that's an automatically generated file (partially edited by adding the last `if` statement) created with a Qt tool, `pyuic`; the naming is generated by the Designer which tries to adhere to the mixedCase naming when creating new objects.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `QDateEdit` already provides a QCalendarWidget so you only need to enable the `calendarPopup` property:

```py
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.dateedit = QtWidgets.QDateEdit(calendarPopup=True)
        self.menuBar().setCornerWidget(self.dateedit, QtCore.Qt.TopLeftCorner)
        self.dateedit.setDateTime(QtCore.QDateTime.currentDateTime())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: thanks @eyllanesc

why default date is shown :01-01-2000
and popup calender also showing 2000 january.
can i able to show current date as default?

Comment: i used this and working fine now for default date
self.dateEdit.setDateTime(QtCore.QDateTime.currentDateTime())

Answer (score 1):

For PyQt6 I had to slightly modify eyllanesc's code. Here's what worked for in in PyQt6. Changes to the original are placed below the commented out code.

```
import sys
from PyQt6 import QtCore, QtWidgets

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.dateedit = QtWidgets.QDateEdit(calendarPopup=True)
        # self.menuBar().setCornerWidget(self.dateedit, QtCore.Qt.TopLeftCorner)
        self.menuBar().setCornerWidget(self.dateedit, QtCore.Qt.Corner.TopLeftCorner)
        self.dateedit.setDateTime(QtCore.QDateTime.currentDateTime())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    # sys.exit(app.exec_())
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```