# Is there a way to insert a QWidget as an item in a QComboBox (instead of a string)?

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyqt5, qt5, pyside

I'd like to have a QCalendarWidget as the only item in a QComboBox, but from what I've looked up, QComboBoxes can only have strings as items. If that's the case, is there a similar implementation that I can use?

[I was hoping to do something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aP6FC.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Look at this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61449954/pyqt5-datepicker-popup), I think it is very similar if not identical to what you are looking for.

I hope this works for you.